# Entity Framework Include with two foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `Team` table and a `Matches` table.

**Team** table:

```
Id Name
------------
1  TeamA
2  TeamB
```

If TeamA desires to play TeamB we will add a row in the `Matches` table

**Matches** table:

```
Id HomeTeamId RivalTeamId
-------------------------
1       1          2
```

If TeamB desires to challenge TeamA we will go about do the following

**Matches** table:

```
Id   HomeTeamId   RivalTeamId
-----------------------------
 1       1             2
 2       2             1
```

My `Team` and `Match` POCO (only relevant code) look like this:

```
public class Team : BaseEntity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Match> RivalMatches { get; set; }
}

public class Match : BaseEntity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //navs
        public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }

        public Team RivalTeam { get; set; }
        public int RivalTeamId { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem**: I guess the experts can already notice a possibility of a cycle up there that I'll come across during query. My problem is that I would like to query TeamA's matches. I would do the following for that

```
 Team team= dbContext.Team.
                Include("HomeMatches").
```

In the above team object I notice that **BOTH** the properties `HomeMatches` and `RivalMatches` appear filled.

I would just want the `HomeMatches` properties filled. I am only interested in those matches which TeamA has chosen to play, not in those where TeamA is a rival.

My question is that when I am clearly mentioned `Include("HomeMatches")`, why is the `RivalMatches` property also filled?

Comment: Do you use lazy loading ? Would you share the complete code which is retrieved data.

Comment: have you tried `[InverseProperty]`?

Comment: which version of ef is this?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane This Is Ef 6. Never heard about inverse prop. How do you suppose that can help ?

Comment: considering you have multiple foreign keys, `InverseProperty` will map them to the right field. So it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Explicit loading as in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I used explicit loading and yes both fields didn't appear filled. Dont know what is the underlying mechanism for that though